# Elastic Search sort by field defined in another field

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I have two fields: count (object) and countyby (text). The count object has several nested properties of type number:

```
"count" : {
    "properties" : 
     "value1" : {
         "type" : "long"
     },
     "value2" : {
         "type" : "long"
     },
     "value3" : {
         "type" : "long"
     },
     "value4" : {
         "type" : "long"
     },
     "value5" : {
         "type" : "long"
     }
 },
 "countBy": {
     type: "keyword"
 }
```

I need to do a search that will sort the documents according to the value of count's nested property that is specified in the countBy property

Comment: So `countBy` contains values such as `value1`, `value2`, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with [script-based sorting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html#_script_based_sorting):

```
"sort" : {
    "_script" : {
        "type" : "number",
        "script" : {
            "lang": "painless",
            "source": "doc['countBy'].value != null ? doc['count.'+doc['countBy'].value].value : 0"
        },
        "order" : "desc"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm getting "Unknown key for a VALUE_STRING in [script]." ES scripts seem a bit difficult to debug. The error messages are not particularly helpful

Comment: Which version of ES are your running?

Comment: 6.5.1. I removed the debug statement and got this: No field found for [count.null] in mapping with types []

Comment: Ok that means some of your documents have no value for `countBy`. I've fixed the script, please try again